# Editing an object in Javascript (deleting a symbol from an array)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I dont know if I put the right title but here is my problem.

```
const lines = [
                { lat: "49.01245", lng: "8.409122" },
                { lat: "49.01184933333333", lng: "8.410966" },
                { lat: "49.01099666666667", lng: "8.413724333333333" },
     ...      ]
```

I actually read this from a csv file using [JQuery-CSV](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv/) by the function called `$.csv.toObjects(csv)`. It gives me in this form but I need those lines in this form below.

```
 const lines = [
                { lat: 49.01245, lng: 8.409122 },
                { lat: 49.01184933333333, lng: 8.410966 },
                { lat: 49.01099666666667, lng: 8.413724333333333 },
  ...          ]
```

So I need to get rid of this (") sign.

Comment: u could use sth like:  `$.each(lines,function(i,line){  line.lat = parseFloat(line.lat)  ... }`

Comment: John comment If using jQuery, if not then use, lines.forEach(line => line.lat = parseFloat(line.lat))

Comment: thanks @johnSmith. it solved my problem real quick.

Comment: @EgeUluçay i´m happy it helped ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array of objects and coerce each string value to a number.

```js
const lines=[{lat:"49.01245",lng:"8.409122"},{lat:"49.01184933333333",lng:"8.410966"},{lat:"49.01099666666667",lng:"8.413724333333333"}];

const out = lines.map(({ lat, lng }) => {
  return { lat: +lat, lng: +lng };
});

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Andy said, "Array.map" is probably the best option in this case.

You can use cast as well to improve readability, instead of using "+" operator, you would do `return { lat: Number(lat), lng: Number(lng) }`